# How do I count how many unique fields a selected column has in query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to get webform submissions. below is the query and what it returns. I need it to return a count of the duplicate sid to get my count of all submissions that satisfy both my data variables. Meaning, I want it to return 4, Any suggestions?

```
SELECT sid, data
FROM webform_submitted_data
INNER JOIN node
ON webform_submitted_data.nid=node.nid
WHERE webform_submitted_data.nid= 15 AND webform_submitted_data.cid = 6 AND webform_submitted_data.data = 'male' OR webform_submitted_data.data = 'yes' AND webform_submitted_data.nid= 15 AND webform_submitted_data.cid= 15;
```

```
sid | Data
-----------
86  | male
86  | yes
87  | yes
88  | yes
90  | yes
91  | male
91  | yes
92  | male
92  | yes
93  | male
93  | yes
94  | yes
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking (and it seems unrelated w.r.t the title), post an example of the result you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by sid and count your data:

```
SELECT sid, COUNT(*) as nb_sid
FROM webform_submitted_data
INNER JOIN node
ON webform_submitted_data.nid=node.nid
WHERE webform_submitted_data.nid= 15
    AND webform_submitted_data.cid = 6 
    AND webform_submitted_data.data = 'male' OR webform_submitted_data.data = 'yes'
    AND webform_submitted_data.nid= 15
    AND webform_submitted_data.cid= 15
GROUP BY sid;
```

You can filter in the where clause the nb_sid if needed. 
You can also get the values in data using `group_concat` if you really need it.

Comment: Thank you. This will work for me, I can iterate over nb_sid checking if it has a value of 2 and add it to my count. I'm not convinced this is the best approach but it will work just fine. Thank you.